# Install systemd timer + service silently with dh_installsystemd

Tags: debian, systemd, systemd-timer

I have a systemd service+timer that I'd like to install which does not match my packagename.

```
# debian/mypackage.myscript.timer
[Timer]
OnCalendar=weekly
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

```
# debian/mypackage.myscript.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myscript
```

```
# debian/rules
%:
        dh $@

override_dh_installsystemd:
        dh_installsystemd --name=myscript
```

But then on install I get:

```
Setting up mypackage (1.38) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/myscript.timer → /lib/systemd/system/myscript.timer.
myscript.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
```

How can I hide that last message?

---

I tried:

```
dh_installsystemd --name=myscript --no-start
```

This does address the installation message.  However, it prevents the timer from starting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat the `*.service` and `*.timer` independently by explicitly defining the unit file:

```
override_dh_installsystemd:
        dh_installsystemd --name=myscript myscript.service --no-start
        dh_installsystemd --name=myscript myscript.timer
```